# Where is the "personal" folder of the iPhone simulator?

Tags: ios-simulator

I found the iPhone simulator at /Username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/ and in there I can see my apps within a cryptic directory name.
One of my apps is storing a database and some cached files in the iPhone's "Personal" folder which I thought is the "Documents" folder in the directory of the simulator. But there's nothing in it. Nevertheless, I can read my files - where are they?

René

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hexadecimal directory name, there is YourApp.app and several folders: Documents, Library, tmp and anything else you created.  If you are saving your files in the documents folder, it should be there.  Make sure to check all the app folders, as your app might be in multiple folders over time.

There can be an unlikely problem, however, if your app isn't saving to the correct path.  The iPhone will not let an app save outside of it's application folder.  However, the simulator does not prevent that from happening.  So you may have saved outside.

Comment: Hmmm. For my sqlite db which is in the project under /data/db.sqlite and is set to "content" and "copy to output folder", I can acces it wit a connection string "source=data/db.sqlite" and it works. Still it is not under the documents folder. What IS the output directory then?

Comment: The DB was in fact not copied to the personal folder. I was accessing it readonly directly inside the app bundle. As soon as I tried to write, it failed and then I noticed. I'm now copying it and it is in the directory as you described it.